# $ p= a^{2} - nb^{2} $ with $ n\in \left\{ -1, -2, -3 \right\} $ quadratic residue modulo a prime p

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

**Problem**

Let $n\in \left\{ -1, -2, -3 \right\} $. If n is a quadratic residue modulo a prime p, then show that
there are integers $ a, b $ such that $ p= a^{2} - nb^{2} $.

**My solution for $ n=-1$**

For Thue's lemma there are two integer such that $at \equiv b \text{ (mod p)}$ with $0 < \left| a \right|, \left| b \right|<\sqrt{p}$ for any $t$ coprime with $p$. So $ a^2t^2 \equiv b^2 \text{ (mod p)}\ \Longrightarrow p|b^2-a^2t^2$. $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. So $-1=t^2 $ for some $t$. So $p|b^2+a^2$ and $0<b^2+a^2<2p$ because $a,b <\sqrt{p}\implies p=a^2+b^2$.

**I need help for $n\in \left\{ -2, -3 \right\}$**

For these cases I have that $a^{2} - nb^{2} <3p $ or $a^{2} - nb^{2} <4p $ for $n=-2, n=-3$ respectively. How can I solve with Thuel's Lemma

Thanks for help.

Comment: These follow since the ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbb Q[\sqrt n]$ is a unique factorization domain for $n=-1,-2,-3.$

Comment: Basically, there is a $u+\sqrt n$ whose norm is divisible by $p,$ and so $p$ must factor non-trivially.

Comment: The case $n=-3$ takes a little more work, since it gives potentially half-integer solutions, $a,b$ to $p=a^2+3b^2.$

Comment: $n=-3$ follows because every element of $\Bbb Z[\zeta_3]$ differs from an element of $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ by a unit. (Plus the unique factorization mentioned)